# How to declare in Laravel 4.x a config array for different environmets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

Having two config files named 'custom' for different environments...

app/config

```
return  [
    'test' => [
        'real_a',
        'real_b',
        'real_c',
    ],
];
```

app/config/local

```
return  [
    'test' => [
        'local_a',
        'local_b',
    ],
];
```

When I work in the 'local' environment and try to recover the test array...

```
Config::get('custom.test');
```

I get

```
'test' => [
    'local_a',
    'local_b',
    'real_c',
],
```

instead of

```
'test' => [
    'local_a',
    'local_b',        
],
```

What is wrong?

Comment: use Config::get('local.test');

Comment: The idea is not having to change the code when changing environment. Just change the $env in start.php

Comment: how is your detectEnvironment set?

Comment: pretty straightforward...

    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
    {
        return 'local';
    });

Comment: Please do `php artisan env` which environment it shows?

Comment: local. The problem is that the local environment array I am getting has a third index with the third value of the array defined for production environment. Seems that the production array is being rewritten by the test environment array but, as the local array has only two indexes the third index of the production array remains.